# Remove css formatting from ::before and ::after selectors

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to use css to change the style of some text but not the ::before and ::after content that I also want to add. But i cant find a way of doing it. I'm using React if that makes a difference.

The text in my .js file is

```
<span className="startMonth">£12</span>
```

My css is:

```
startMonth {
  text-decoration: line-through ;
  color:red;

}
.startMonth::before {
  text-decoration: none !important ;
  content: "Special Offer ";
  color: red;
}
.startMonth::after {
  text-decoration: none !important ;
  content: " FREE";
}
```

ie. I want only the £12 to have a line through, but the result is a line through all the text. Any way I can do it without editing the .js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to change the view without editing anything from JS

```
.startMonth {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    padding-left: 81px;
    position: "relative"
}
.startMonth::before {
    content: "Special Offer";
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.startMonth::after {
    content: "FREE";
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
    left: 116px;
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KirankumarDafda/ux9pho4a/2/) example

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning to prevent children pseudo-elements to inherit parent's `text-decoration` as shown below:

```css
.startMonth {
  color:red;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.startMonth::before, .startMonth::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
 }
.startMonth::before {
  top: 100%;
  content: "Special Offer ";
}
.startMonth::after {
  top: 200%;
  content: " FREE";
}
```

```html
<p class="startMonth">£12</p>
```

A cleaner way is to use a container for your text:

```css
.startMonth {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color:red;
}

.container::before {
  content: "Special Offer ";
}
.container::after {
  content: " FREE";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="startMonth">£12</p>
</div>
```